# MYSQL QUERY: SELECT DISTINCT IMEI from query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am querying to have an output that will get the latest data from database without any duplicates in IMEI, i want that the most recent values will only be seen in output and will disregard the second succeeding value that has the same IMEI..

this is my QUERY:

```
SELECT 
tblWeather.humidity, tblWeather.rainfall,
tblWeather.wDate, tblWeather.wTime,
tblStations.IMEI, tblStations.Station, 
tblWeather.IMEI, tblWeather.msgID,
tblWeather.tempture 
FROM tblStations 
INNER JOIN tblWeather ON tblStations.IMEI = tblWeather.IMEI 
ORDER BY msgID DESC LIMIT 0,22
```

the output of this would be:

```
{
"tblStations": [
    {
        "Station": "AWS09 - Lasang",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "25.2",
        "humidity": "92.4",
        "rainfall": "4.42"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS0C - AdDU",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "25.4",
        "humidity": "88.6",
        "rainfall": "6.2"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS0A - Marilog",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "22.6",
        "humidity": "94.6",
        "rainfall": "1.42"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS12 - AdDU HS",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "26",
        "humidity": "89.5",
        "rainfall": "4.37"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS0D - Lacuesta",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:00",
        "temperature": "18.5",
        "humidity": "98.5",
        "rainfall": "7.99"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS04 - DNSC",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "25.6",
        "humidity": "92.7",
        "rainfall": "2.69"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS14 - Catigan",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "25.4",
        "humidity": "78.9",
        "rainfall": "0.3"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS10 - Tamugan",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "25.4",
        "humidity": "89.9",
        "rainfall": "1.59"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS05 - Panacan",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "25.7",
        "humidity": "92.9",
        "rainfall": "2.2"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS03 - UPMin",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "25.9",
        "humidity": "83.2",
        "rainfall": "0"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS11 - Mudiang",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "24.9",
        "humidity": "92.2",
        "rainfall": "1.66"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS07 - Unlad Kabayan",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "26.5",
        "humidity": "82.6",
        "rainfall": "0.21"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS13 - Calinan",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "26.5",
        "humidity": "83.9",
        "rainfall": "0"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS01 - USeP",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:15:01",
        "temperature": "26.9",
        "humidity": "86.4",
        "rainfall": "1.63"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS11 - Mudiang",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:00:01",
        "temperature": "25.1",
        "humidity": "92.2",
        "rainfall": "1.62"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS0C - AdDU",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:00:01",
        "temperature": "25.3",
        "humidity": "89.9",
        "rainfall": "6.2"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS0D - Lacuesta",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:00:00",
        "temperature": "18.5",
        "humidity": "98.4",
        "rainfall": "7.79"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS03 - UPMin",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:00:01",
        "temperature": "25.7",
        "humidity": "83.1",
        "rainfall": "0"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS10 - Tamugan",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:00:01",
        "temperature": "25.3",
        "humidity": "90",
        "rainfall": "1.58"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS04 - DNSC",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:00:01",
        "temperature": "25.9",
        "humidity": "92",
        "rainfall": "2.66"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS05 - Panacan",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:00:01",
        "temperature": "25.7",
        "humidity": "92.8",
        "rainfall": "2.18"
    },
    {
        "Station": "AWS13 - Calinan",
        "Date": "2014-03-19",
        "Time": "16:00:01",
        "temperature": "26.7",
        "humidity": "84.5",
        "rainfall": "0"
    }
],
```

what i want to get is to only get one data from each station, and not get any duplicate data from each station

the stations IMEI is the unique value for each station.

can you help me please... thank you very much/..

i tried doing distinct query but i seem to get no values from the query..

Comment: This would be really easy to mock up if you created an sql fiddle for me ... as is I'll only be able to provide a general answer.

Comment: to receive one entry per station, `group by {station_identifier}`. To get the latest entry, `sort by {time_identifier} ASC`

Comment: Ah, but you can't combine those two methods.

Comment: @DanFarrell You can?! Entries will be sorted first by time, then distinguished by station_id. All good.

Comment: The problem is that the result you'll get for each station won't necessarily correspond to the most recent row.  IF you want the most recent message for each station, you can't just SELECT MAX(time/id), * FROM weatherTbl GROUP BY IMEI - the MAX won't necessarily correspond with the rest of the data pulled.

Comment: @DanFarrell yes i have noticed that i tried something like that and i only get only one output... is there nothing to be done? other than that which you have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll want to get the messages from the most recent message ID from each station.  The issue is there's no super simple way in SQL to do this kind of thing.  You'll need to pull data into a temporary table (either explicity or implicitly with a subquery) so that you can then join the most recent IDs for each station to the weather data.

A process like this would work well for you:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE latest_messages 
SELECT MAX(msgID, IMEI) FROM tblWeather 
GROUP BY IMEI;
```

The benefit of putting it into an explicit temporary table is that you can index that table for later joins, a technique that only really matters if latest_messages becomes pretty big.  Joining against a subquery would likely be adequate.  If the data is just too massive for both these techniques, then you'll probably want a trigger or manual method to update `latest_messages` whenever an update comes in.

Then once you have the most recent messages from each station, you could then join that temporary table against tblWeather to find the most recent weather data for each station.

If you can't or don't want to create a temporary table, you might try something like this:

```
  select * from  (
    SELECT MAX(msgID, IMEI) newest_id FROM tblWeather 
    GROUP BY IMEI
   ) AS most_recent_messages 
   JOIN tblWeather on newest_id = tblWeather.msgID
   JOIN tblStations on tblStations.IMEI = tblWeather.IMEI;
```

Hope it helps!  Create an SQLFiddle if you need a more specific example.  I tire of rebuilding people's schemas :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i really dont have this option since i am only connecting from a PHP file and i have limited access to the database.. i cant create there i can only SELECT.. osrry for not putting that up...

Comment: You can still do this with a subquery.  Take a look at the edit I just added.

Answer (score 0):

You can Sort the entries by date first, then group by any {station_identifier} - voila, you have the latest entry per station:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY c_time DESC) as temp  GROUP BY station;
```

See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8a28/1

Maybe my comment was a bit unclear: ofc. within one query that does not work (without min/max). But you dont have to mess arround with Min/Max or whatever to get the newest entry per "grouping unit".

Sitenote: on MsSQL this will not work: Mysql will pick the "first" result in case of an ambigious grouping without defining an aggregation on other columns (which is defined by our sorting done prior) - MsSQL will throw an error.

---

explanation:

Assuming the Rows

```
foreign_id | date | msg
1 | 2014-03-23 00:00:00 | Newest Message
1 | 2014-03-22 00:00:00 | Older Message
```

Mysql will sort them as given. Finally it will group by id, and picking the first row, due to grouping (and the first row of each group is what we need - due to sorting): `2014-03-23 00:00:00` and `Newest Message` as the result.

on MsSQL, you need to give `MAX(date)` which then will cleary define `1 | 2014-03-23 00:00:00` - However, MsSQL would not know, what to do with the msg column: Should it pick `Newest Message` or `Older Message`? That's because an Aggregation on THAT column is missing and MsSQL has no implicit sorting on this, because BOTH values are matching the Group By criteria `id=1`.

Comment: @Adrian it simple defines the SubSelect as temporary table. For more complex queries you could refer to each column of that subquery with `temp.columnName`. Even if you dont need it, an Alias is mandatory for sub-queries.